# Time = distance over speed in C

Tags: c, time

I'm trying to find the time taken to travel over an inputted distance going at a constant speed in C. The code I have functions but the output is printed as 0? Any idea what is going wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int distance, speed = 80;
    float time;

    // This is how to read an int value
    printf("Please enter a distance in kilometers to be covered at 80KPH. \n");
    scanf("%d", & distance);
    printf("You typed: %d\n", distance);
    printf("\n");
    time = distance / speed;
    printf("It will take you %.2f to cover ", time);
}
```

Comment: Good computer programs move at the speed of C.

Comment: ..where `c= 299792458 m/s`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because the two operands are integers, the compiler generates code for integer division. But you want real division. So cast one or more of the operands to a floating point type and the compiler will emit code for real division.

```
time = (float) distance / time;
```

Integer division is what you learnt in elementary school. So, 11/3 is 3 remainder 2, for example. In C the expression 11/3 evaluates to 3. This is integer division. In your case it seems that the numerator (distance) is less than the denominator (time) and so the expression

```
distance / time
```

evaluates to 0.

This is a common confusion caused by the overloading of the division operator. This operator means integer division if both operands are integers, otherwise it is real division.

The key point to learn is that it is the *types of the operands* that determine whether integer or real division is used. The type of the variable in which the result is stored has no influence on this choice.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
time = distance / speed;
```

to

```
time = (float) distance / speed;
```

You were doing an integer division instead of a floating point division.

Comment: @haccks speed of light! :)

Comment: While I was answering this question, I decided not to answer after seeing your speed (now I have to work on my typing speed). :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you changed the code according to what the others said (cast to float or double first), you will also need to change the format specifier from "%d" to "%f" for displaying floating point numbers (be it float or double), or else you will see garbage in your output.

EDIT: Sorry for mixing this up. I was thinking of a fix where you define speed and distance as float instead of int. In that case, you can simply convert "int" to "float" and "%d" to "%f" (possibly with accuracy and/or rounding flags). However, this will change the way the program works (because the user can now enter non-integral values), so it might not be what you want.

Comment: I explained myself in my post. Sorry about that.